# Llamar una class desde el MainActivity o Importar class de otro proyecto Android studio

Tags: java, android

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion la cual no estará en el market "google play" por lo que añadí un AutoUpdate para mantener la aplicacion al dia, resulta que el autoupdate lo hice **creando otro proyecto** (si, no lo hice directamente desde la app que estoy desarrollando, pues quería evitarme mover tanto código, evitar la demora por compilar (tengo una cafetera, por lo que al compilar si que tarda xD) y pensé que creando otro proyecto para el autoupdate era mas fácil y rápido, ya una vez terminado el codigo solo quedaba **implementarlo/añadir/importar** en la app principal.) entonces, este autoupdate en el manifiesto está como:

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**Y el codigo completo del MainActivity**

```
/*
 * Actualizador de Apk sin Market Google Play
 *
 *
 * Confirma la version actual con una remota
 * Muestra los cambios
 * Descarga la nueva apk
 * La ejecuta y ya es parte del usuario instalarla.
 *
 *
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static  String url = "localhost/version.json";
    String VersionUpdate;
    String Cambios;
    String link;
    String nombre;
    String ejecutar;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new VersionCheck().execute();
        permission_check();

    }

    private void permission_check() {
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},100);
                return;
            }
        }

        //initialize();
    }

    private class VersionCheck extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
            if (jsonStr != null){
                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    JSONArray obtener = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Obtener");
                    for (int i = 0; i < obtener.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject v = obtener.getJSONObject(i);
                        link = v.getString("link");
                        VersionUpdate = v.getString("version");
                        nombre = v.getString("nombre");
                        Cambios = "";
                        JSONArray cambiosArr = v.getJSONArray("cambios");
                        for (int j = 0; j < cambiosArr.length(); j++) {
                            Cambios += cambiosArr.getString(j) + "\n";
                        }
                    }
                }catch (final JSONException e) {

                    // Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "El formato de JSON es invalido: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "El servidor de comprobar la version esta caido, por favor chequear la version en: Ajustes > Comprobar",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute (Void result){

            if (VersionUpdate != null) {

                super.onPostExecute(result);
                String VersionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
                if (VersionUpdate.equals(VersionName)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Version actual: " + VersionName,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                } else {

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Actualización");
                    builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                    builder.setCancelable(false);
                    builder.setMessage("Actual: "+ VersionName + "\n"+ "Disponible: " + VersionUpdate  + "\n" + "\n" + "Incluye: " +"\n" +"\n" + Cambios + "\n")

                            .setPositiveButton("¡Actualizame!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    //Ejecutamos el class para descargar la version
                                    new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(link);

                                }
                            });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Despues", null);


                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();


                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
        switch (id){
            case progress_bar_type:
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Descargando actualización"+"\n"+"Espere...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setMax(100);
                pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
                return pDialog;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }

        @Override
        protected  String doInBackground(String... f_url){
            int count;
            try{
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();

                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                String storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                String fileName = "/download/"+nombre+VersionUpdate+".apk";
                File arch = new File(storageDir+fileName);
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(arch);
                ejecutar = storageDir+fileName;
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;

                while((count = input.read(data)) != -1){
                    total += count;

                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                output.flush();

                output.close();
                input.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                //Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;

        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress){
            pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){
            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
             //aca ejecutamos al finalizar la descarga
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(ejecutar)),
                    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // without this flag android returned a intent error!
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

}
```

**Y en la app principal (que es la que estoy desarrollando) tengo en el manifiesto:**

```
<activity
        android:name=".NavigatorActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:label="XploiT" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**Ahora, mi pregunta:** ¿Como fusionar, importar, añadir el código "AutoUpdate", a la aplicación principal?

Hice el intento de Copiar y pegar el **AutoUpdate** sin embargo no se como llamar este desde **NavigatorActivity**

Answer (score 1):

Para importar activities desde un proyecto a otro simplemente tienes que guardar el proyecto que quieres exportar como una librería y luego en en el proyecto que quieres importarla simplemente añadiendo otra libreria como cualquier otra en:

> Project Properties > Android > Add Library

O también echaría un vistazo a

> File >Import >Android >Existing Code into Workspace

Para añadir librerias externas una vez exportada:

> File > Project Structure > Dependencies Tab > Add module dependency

Y si te refieres al código es como cualquier otra libreria:

En la raíz de tu proyecto edita el `settings.gradle` y añade esta línea

```
include 'MiApp', ':subProject:NombreDeTuLibreria'
```

Acto seguido limpia el proyecto para asegurarte de que todo funciona

```
gradle clean & build/close the project
```

y añade a tu `build.gradle` la siguiente dependencia:

```
dependencies {
//...
    compile project(':subProject:NombreDeTuLibreria')

}
```

Comment: Uhmm y en este caso de guardar el activity como librería, en el proyecto principal, como llamaría la librería al abrir la app?

Comment: @LuisRivas perdón he cometido un fallo ahora arreglo mi respuesta

Comment: @LuisRivas ya está

Comment: Ya logre hacer lo que quería, me dio muchos problemas al intentar hacer lo que me planteaste. Sin embargo lo que hice fue crear una nueva clase como ya lo había hecho y llamar la clase como si fuera un activity.  `Intent uppp = new Intent(this, AutoUpdate.class);
  startActivity(uppp);` Pero esto hace que me abra otro activity D: lo cual no deseo, solo quiero llamar la class sin estar creando un activity. Es posible? Intente con esto `AutoUpdate myClase = new AutoUpdate();
myClase;` Y no me funciono. Aclaro que al abrir como activity la .class me funciona el codigo a la perfección.